# How can I find by ID in Mongo C# Driver 2.2.3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, mongodb-.net-driver

My source code is not working

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AdjustPrice(string id)
{
    var filter = new BsonDocument("_id",id);                     
    return View(await Context.Rentals().Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's working now.

```
public async Task<ActionResult> AdjustPrice(string id)
{
    var filter = Builders<Rentals>.Filter.Eq("Id",id);                     
    return View(await Context.Rentals().Find(filter).FirstOrDefaultAsync());
}
```